# Diff between Subscription and Subscriber<T> angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscription, rxjs5, angular2-observables

While I was working on some project I came across this type `Subscriber<T>`. I am not able to declare a property with appropriate type.

Problem is when I do,

```
let sub = this._api.getDefaultMedia().subscriptions.play.subscribe(
            () => {
                this.play();
            }
        );
console.log(sub);
```

It prints me the following which is of type `Subscriber`

[image]

But if I try to assign a variable which is of type `Subscription`

```
private subPlay : Subscription;

 this.subPlay = this._api.getDefaultMedia().subscriptions.play.subscribe(
            () => {
                this.play();
            }
        );
```

It gives me the following error Type `Subscription` is not assignable to type `Subscription`

[image]

Even though it says it is returning `Subscription`, when I do console it is of type `Subscriber`.

So what is the difference or similarity between these two?

Comment: What are your imports? What is the type of `this._api.getDefaultMedia().subscriptions.play`? Regarding your last question, that's just polymorphism: Subscriber extends Subscription. You're not suprised to get a Ford when renting a Car, because a Ford is a Car. Same here.

Comment: `this._api.getDefaultMedia().subscriptions.play` is returning `Observable<any>`. Its a `videogular2` event.

Comment: What are your imports?

Comment: For some reason unable to edit my question, don't know why is that so. `import {VgAPI} from "videogular2/src/core/services/vg-api";
import {Observable, Subscription} from "rxjs";`

Comment: Don't, ever, import from rxjs. That will cause the whole library to be embedded inside your app, although you probably only use some of its classes an operators. Use `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';`

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to this:

1. *Type `Subscription` is not assignable to type `Subscription`*.

   I bet you imported or declared some other `Subscription` class and now TypeScript tries to assign the original `Subscription` form `rxjs` package to your custom `Subscription` class. That's why it complains that `_subscriptions` property is missing which can't happen otherwise.
   See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subscription.ts#L45.
2. The `subscribe()` method really returns an instance of `Subscriber` class.

   However [`Subscriber` extends the `Subscription` class](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subscriber.ts#L17) so the types are correct. If you're using TypeScript the compiler won't let you do any malicious stuff but if you were using just ES6 you could exploit this. I had a comment on one of RxJS's issues regarding exactly this situation: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2487#issuecomment-288976689.

As a rule of thumb, if you're unsure what instances are returned from function calls always have a look at the `.d.ts` file. This is recommended by the creators of RxJS themselves.

The `subscribe()` call is also not the only place you can encounter behavior. For example all `window*()` operators emit an instance of `Subject` instead of `Observable`. The same applies for `retryWhen()` and `retryWhen()` operators.

Some time ago I made a PR to RxJS regarding forcing `Observable`s instead of `Subject`s and it was closed for the reasons I summarized here. You can have a look at them in the following links if you're interested in more indepth explanation:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2391
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2408
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2487#issuecomment-288871607

Comment: In my code I am using the Subscription properly. `import {Subscription} from "rxjs/Subscription";`. The event that I am subscribing to; can be found here https://github.com/videogular/videogular2/blob/master/src/core/vg-media/i-playable.ts  and https://github.com/videogular/videogular2/blob/master/src/core/vg-media/vg-media.ts

Comment: I have put the code in an image which shows error. The same line.

Comment: @AmitChigadani I really can't help you when the only thing I can look at is one line of code in an image...

Comment: Same code I have written in question as well. For some reason I am unable to edit my question since one hour. `this.subPlay=this._api.getDefaultMedia().subscriptions.play.subscribe() // error is shown in this line`

Comment: I saw this but I wanted to see the entire file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145181/discussion-between-amit-chigadani-and-martin).

Comment: @AmitChigadani You can push the working version in a separate branch so I can try to compile it locally.